# SQL Server Deadlock on two updates due to index lock order

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have two UPDATEs - one locks the CI first and then the NCI (on status) because the status column is also being updated.  The other already owns a U lock on the NCI because it knows it is changing and then tries to get a U lock on the CI.

What is the easiest way to force these to serialize?  It seems odd to use a TABLE-level hint since this is an internal indexing issue - there is only one table involved - will UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK automatically just apply to all indexes needed on that table and thereby force it to be serialized?

Here are the queries:

```
UPDATE htt_action_log
SET status = 'ABORTED', CLOSED = GETUTCDATE()
WHERE transition_uuid = '{F53ADDDA-E46B-4726-66D8-D7B640B66597}'
AND status = 'OPEN';
```

That one X locks the row in the CI (on CREATED column) and then attempts to X lock on the NCI which includes the status column.

```
UPDATE htt_action_log
SET status = 'RUNNING {36082BCD-EB52-4358-E3D3-4D96FD5B9F0F} 1360094342'
WHERE action_uuid = (SELECT TOP 1 action_uuid
                     FROM htt_action_log
                     WHERE transition_uuid = '{F53ADDDA-E46B-4726-66D8-D7B640B66597}'
                         AND status = 'OPEN'
                     ORDER BY action_seq)
```

This one U locks the same NCI - for the nested query I guess, then goes to lock the CI for the update.

Thus the order produces the deadlock.

Easiest solution is to force the two queries to completely block - i.e. serialize.  What's the easiest way to force that, just put `WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` on the references to the table (one in the first and two in the second)?

DDL:

Note client has more indexes on this table which should be affected by this update, but are not mentioned in the deadlock graph.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[HTT_ACTION_LOG](
    [ACTION_UUID] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [TRANSITION_UUID] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [STATUS] [varchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [CREATED] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CLOSED] [datetime] NULL,
    [ACTION_SEQ] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ACTION_TYPE] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [ACTION_NAME] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ACTION_RESULT] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [PENDING_SINCE] [datetime] NULL,
    [ACTION_SQL] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [ERROR_OK] [int] NULL,
    [ERROR_COND] [varchar](2048) NULL,
    [RETRY] [varchar](128) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_HTT_ACTION_LOG_1] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ACTION_UUID] ASC
)
)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IK_HTT_ACTION_LOG_2] ON [dbo].[HTT_ACTION_LOG] 
(
    [CREATED] ASC
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IK_HTT_ACTION_LOG_1] ON [dbo].[HTT_ACTION_LOG] 
(
    [TRANSITION_UUID] ASC,
    [STATUS] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [ACTION_UUID],
[ACTION_SEQ])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IK_HTT_ACTION_LOG_4] ON [dbo].[HTT_ACTION_LOG] 
(
    [ACTION_UUID] ASC,
    [STATUS] ASC
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [missing_index_11438530_11438529_HTT_ACTION_LOG] ON [dbo].[HTT_ACTION_LOG] 
(
    [TRANSITION_UUID] ASC,
    [ACTION_TYPE] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [ACTION_NAME])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [missing_index_7207590_7207589_HTT_ACTION_LOG] ON [dbo].[HTT_ACTION_LOG] 
(
    [STATUS] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [CREATED],
[PENDING_SINCE],
[ACTION_NAME])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [missing_index_8535421_8535420_HTT_ACTION_LOG] ON [dbo].[HTT_ACTION_LOG] 
(
    [TRANSITION_UUID] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [ACTION_UUID],
[STATUS])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HTT_ACTION_LOG] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = AUTO)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HTT_ACTION_LOG]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_HTT_ACTION_LOG_1] FOREIGN KEY([TRANSITION_UUID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[HTT_TRANSITION_LOG] ([TRANSITION_UUID])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HTT_ACTION_LOG] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_HTT_ACTION_LOG_1]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HTT_ACTION_LOG] ADD  DEFAULT ('OPEN') FOR [STATUS]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HTT_ACTION_LOG] ADD  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [CREATED]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[HTT_ACTION_LOG] ADD  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ERROR_OK]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The optimal index for those two queries is not far from the existing definition of the `IK_HTT_ACTION_LOG_1` index (add `ACTION_UUID` as an `INCLUDE` to the improved index below):

```
CREATE INDEX nc1
ON dbo.HTT_ACTION_LOG
(
    TRANSITION_UUID,
    STATUS,
    ACTION_SEQ
);
```

The first query is:

```
UPDATE dbo.HTT_ACTION_LOG
SET [STATUS] = 'ABORTED', 
    CLOSED = GETUTCDATE()
WHERE
    TRANSITION_UUID = '{F53ADDDA-E46B-4726-66D8-D7B640B66597}'
    AND [STATUS] = 'OPEN';
```

Giving the following execution plan:

[image: Update 1]

The second query can be expressed this way:

```
UPDATE ToUpdate 
SET [STATUS] = 'RUNNING {36082BCD-EB52-4358-E3D3-4D96FD5B9F0F} 1360094342'
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP (1)
        hal.[STATUS]
    FROM dbo.HTT_ACTION_LOG AS hal
    WHERE
        hal.transition_uuid = '{F53ADDDA-E46B-4726-66D8-D7B640B66597}'
        AND hal.[STATUS] = 'OPEN'
    ORDER BY
        hal.ACTION_SEQ ASC
) AS ToUpdate;
```

Giving this execution plan:

[image: Update 2]

Both queries now access the same resources in the same order, while locking many fewer rows on the read side of the plan. The execution engine will automatically take `UPDLOCK`s when reading the new index, providing the serialization you are looking for.